# I am trying to remove Items from a list with an on-click, what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove an item every time it is clicked on but only a single item at a time (the item that was clicked on) when trying to make a 'to-do' list.  I can easily remove all simultaneously but I am having a lot of issues trying to do it at an individual level.  I thought this would work but hoping to get a second set of eyes on it.

```
 var toDoCount = 0;
 var todoarray = [];

window.onload = function() {
//user clicked on the add button in the to-do field add that text into the to-do text
$('#add-to-do').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //assign variable to the value entered into the textbox
    var value = document.getElementById('to-do').value; 
    //test value
    console.log(value);

    var todoitem = $("#to-dos");
    todoitem.attr("item-");
    //prepend values into the html and add checkmark, checkbox, and line break to make list
    var linebreak = "<br/>";
    var todoclose = $("<button>");
    todoclose.attr("data-to-do", toDoCount);
    todoclose.addClass("checkbox");
    todoclose.text("☑");

    //prepend values to html
    $("#to-dos").prepend(linebreak);
    $("#to-dos").prepend(value);
    $("#to-dos").prepend(todoclose);
    toDoCount++;

todoarray.push(value);

console.log(todoarray);

//to remove item from checklist
$(document.body).on("click", ".checkbox", function() {
var toDoNumber = $(this).attr("data-to-do");
$("#item-" + toDoNumber).remove();

});


});

}
```

HTML is below

```
                <div class ="col-4">
                <!-- To Do List -->
                <form onsubmit= "return false;">
                    <span id = "todo-item" type = "text">
                    <h4>Add your Agenda Here</h4>
                    <input id ="to-do" type = "text">
                    <input id ="add-to-do" value = "Add Item" type = "submit">
                    </span>
                </form>
             <div id="to-dos"></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you add a working jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't need the number, just the element.

change...

```
$("#item-" + toDoNumber).remove();
```

to...

```
$(this).remove();
```

e.g.

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".checkbox", function() {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Ah this makes sense and works! Thanks for the help I think I've been staring at it for to long lol